# Are abusive or offensive words allowed here?

Tags: support

Some users are putting abusive/offensive words for their name like [this](https://superuser.com/users/199298/beti-chode). Is this type of thing allowed on such a good site?

Comment: I think its less than obvious , I had to look it up to work out why it was offensive (and boy did I regret it), and one meaning was vulgar slang, and the other an old fashioned past tense of chide. In any case with something like this, there's no real way to automatically fiter words out without unintended consequences. However, if it is brought to moderator attention, its usually taken care of.

Comment: What do you suggest? Auto delete or auto-prevent? Then you get false positive (such as the cursed filters which prevented my from looking up the trains to Essex). That cure might be worse than the disease.

Comment: I think the OP might not have realised that people from all over the world use this site, but the primary language of the company itself (given its location) and most of the staff is English. Thus it's not possible for vulgarities from all languages to be recognised immediately. Best thing to do as suggested is let the mods know, and once they look into it the issue's sure to be handled satisfactorily.

Comment: As @Karan said, this is impossible to automate. There are words that are offensive in one language and completely neutral in others. For example [bitte](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitte) means please in German and is a vulgar term for penis in French.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you consider a user's username or user picture to be offensive, please flag one of their posts to inform the moderation team, and we will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Offensive usernames are not allowed, but there is no mechanism for automatically blocking such names (this would result in false positives).  If you encounter an offensive username, flag any one of the user's posts for moderator attention, and a moderator will edit the username.

For more information, see [Offensive Username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103292/offensive-username) on Meta Stack Overflow.